# Problem getting specific class using getElementsByClassName() (multiple classes with similar names)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to parse track names from [Discogs.com html](https://www.discogs.com/Bark-Psychosis-Codename-Dustsucker/release/942074). Here is an example of the part of the html:

```
<tr class=" tracklist_track track" data-track-position="8">
        <td class="tracklist_track_pos">8</td>  
        <td class="track tracklist_track_title ">
            <span class="tracklist_track_title">Shapeshifting</span><blockquote><span class="tracklist_extra_artist_span">Vocals – <a href="/artist/764815-Rachel-Dreyer">Rachel Dreyer</a></span></blockquote></td>
        <td width="25" class="tracklist_track_duration">
            <span>6:02</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
<tr class=" tracklist_track track" data-track-position="9">
        <td class="tracklist_track_pos">9</td>
        <td class="track tracklist_track_title ">
            <span class="tracklist_track_title">Rose</span><blockquote><span class="tracklist_extra_artist_span">Vocals – <a href="/artist/764814-Silke-Roch">Silke Roch</a></span></blockquote></td>
        <td width="25" class="tracklist_track_duration">
            <span>5:49</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

My goal is to extract `innerText` of class `tracklist_track_title` (`"Shapeshifting", "Rose"`).

If I try this: `document.getElementsByClassName("tracklist_track_title")`, I'm receiving array, which includes classes `track tracklist_track_title`, `tracklist_track_title` and `tracklist_extra_artist_span`. (`"Shapeshifting", "Shapeshifting", "Vocals – Rachel Dreyer", "Rose", "Rose", "Vocals – Silke Roch"`)

If I try this: `document.getElementsByClassName("track tracklist_track_title")`, I'm receiving only `track tracklist_track_title` class, but unfortunately class `tracklist_extra_artist_span` is included as well. (`"Shapeshifting", "Vocals – Rachel Dreyer", "Rose", "Vocals – Silke Roch"`).

Can you please, suggest me a way to include only `tracklist_track_title` in resulting array, or maybe filter this array afterwards to get rid of `tracklist_extra_artist_span` class? (`"Shapeshifting", "Rose"`).

The only idea I have is to use `document.getElementsByClassName("tracklist_track_title")` and then filter all the elements with even index from the resulting array to get rid of `track tracklist_track_title` class:

```
var trackBlock = document.getElementsByClassName("tracklist_track_title");
var trackList = [];
for (var i = 0; i < trackBlock.length; i++) {
    if(i % 2 != 0) { // index is not even
        trackList.push(trackBlock[i].innerText);
    }
}
```

Any other ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll` instead, and select only `<span>` tags with the `tracklist_track_title`, with `span.tracklist_track_title`:

```js
const trackList = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('span.tracklist_track_title'),
  span => span.textContent
);
console.log(trackList);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class=" tracklist_track track" data-track-position="8">
    <td class="tracklist_track_pos">8</td>
    <td class="track tracklist_track_title ">
      <span class="tracklist_track_title">Shapeshifting</span>
      <blockquote><span class="tracklist_extra_artist_span">Vocals – <a href="/artist/764815-Rachel-Dreyer">Rachel Dreyer</a></span></blockquote>
    </td>
    <td width="25" class="tracklist_track_duration">
      <span>6:02</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class=" tracklist_track track" data-track-position="9">
    <td class="tracklist_track_pos">9</td>
    <td class="track tracklist_track_title ">
      <span class="tracklist_track_title">Rose</span>
      <blockquote><span class="tracklist_extra_artist_span">Vocals – <a href="/artist/764814-Silke-Roch">Silke Roch</a></span></blockquote>
    </td>
    <td width="25" class="tracklist_track_duration">
      <span>5:49</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Selector strings are far more powerful and flexible than the `getElementsBy` methods.

`span.tracklist_track_title` means: select elements with a tag name of `span` which also have a class name of `tracklist_track_title`.